# Task.json dataSourceBindings Select Azure Ressource Group to display its location

Tags: json, azure-devops

I'm developping a custom extension for Azure marketplace.
Iam trying to make something that sound simple.
Give the user the ability to select the Ressource group, then based on this ressource group, get a field with the location.

To reach my goal, I have created 2 input in the task.json.

One input for the ressource group:

```
        {
        "name": "ResourceGroupName",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Resource group",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "groupName": "Global",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Resource Group Name",
        "properties": {
            "EditableOptions": "True"
        }
    },
```

One input for the location:

```
    {
        "name": "ResourceGroupLocation",
        "type": "pickList",
        "label": "Location",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "groupName": "Global",
        "required": true,
        "helpMarkDown": "Location"
    },
```

Then, in the Datasourcebinding section, I have created to datasource, one for the ressource group:

```
        {
        "target": "ResourceGroupName",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "dataSourceName": "AzureResourceGroups"
    },
```

Another one for the location:

```
    {
        "target": "ResourceGroupLocation",
        "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
        "endpointUrl": "{{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(ResourceGroupName)?api-version=2019-10-01",
        "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*].location"
    },
```

For the moment, the result of this code, let me select the ressource group I want (the Datasourcebinding work for the resourcegroup), but it do not display anything for the location.

Does anybody have already done something similar ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the problem,

```
 {
    "target": "ResourceGroupLocation",
    "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
    "endpointUrl": "{{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(ResourceGroupName)?api-version=2019-10-01",
    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$"
},
```

instead of

```
 {
    "target": "ResourceGroupLocation",
    "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
    "endpointUrl": "{{{endpoint.url}}}/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(ResourceGroupName)?api-version=2019-10-01",
    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*].location"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)